# How to Unittest ExceptionHandling on BufferedReader - IOException

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, bufferedreader

I'm reading a file with a BufferedReader. So far no problem. When Unittesting my Code I'm struggeling to provoke an IOException. See the Following Code as example:

```
public List<String> readCSV(InputStreamReader in){
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

   try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in)) {
       reader.lines().forEach(line -> list.add(line));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       log.error("Something went wrong while reading file");
   }

   return list;
}
```

I can unit test that my code is reading all the lines from the give file or that there is no file found ...

I don't see a way to mock the BufferedReader... so I can't throw the exception and I have no idea how else to do it...

How could I test the behavior if an IOException occures if I can't make it occure in a testcase?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Whether or not BufferedReader throws an exception per its specification is something I for one am prepared to take as given - it does not need testing.  I'd never get anything done if I had to test the entire Java library. And all you do on the exception is to log something, which surely does not need explicit testing if 'log' is already tested.

Comment: As I wrote my code is an example.  But depending on the customer needs it could be urgent to have a specific statement logged (or somethings else done) which then should require me to provide a test for it.